# Get currency applied to an Excel Cell using POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have written a Java program to read an Excel file cell-by-cell using POI API.
The setting of the currency is done explicitly using the MS Excel - "Format Cell" option.

However, is there any way in which I can recognize the currency that has been applied to the cell using POI?

So far, I have tried using getCellStyle().getDataFormat() and it returns a unique number.  However, the problem is that it is based on the cell style, and can change with a change in the cell formatting(font, size, etc.).

I tried this:

```
if(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
{
  System.out.println("Value in Excel cell:: " + cell.getNumericCellValue());
  short styleType = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat();
  System.out.println("style (currency):: " + styleType);

  if(styleType == <Some unique number>)  //want this unique number
  {
    System.out.println("Currency applied to this cell:: " + <Currency name>);
  }
}
```

So, either I get the unique number which identifies the currency name or if I get the currency name directly, then that would be the best.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can identify the built in format by id looking at [org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.BuiltinFormats](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/BuiltinFormats.html) class, or get the format string using the same class

```
 String dataFormatString =
 BuiltinFormats.getBuiltinFormat(cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormat());
```

or you can get the currency format using the `getDataFormatString()` method from the `CellStyle`

```
String dataFormatString = cell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString();
```

**Update:**

Looking at [HSSFDataFormat](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/hssf/usermodel/HSSFDataFormat.html) class

> **International Formats**
>
> Since version 2003 Excel has supported international formats. These
>   are denoted with a prefix "[$-xxx]" (where xxx is a 1-7 digit
>   hexadecimal number). See the Microsoft article 
>   [Creating international number formats](https://office.microsoft.com/assistance/hfws.aspx?AssetID=HA010346351033&CTT=6&Origin=EC010272491033) for more details on these codes.

For currency format the prefix really is `[$c-xxx]` where `c` is the currency symbol and `xxx` is the hexadecimal value of the Locale Identifier (LCID) for the appropriate language and location, so you can parse the data format string to get the currency.

An example, for currency `"EUR € Spanish (Spain)"` the data format string is `#.##0 [$€-C0A];-#.##0 [$€-C0A]` so you can translate `[$€-C0A]` in `"Currency EUR - Spanish"`, for `"USD $ English (EE. UU.)"` the data format string is `[$$-409]#.##0;-[$$-409]#.##0` so you can translate `[$$-409]` in `"Currency USD - English (U.S.)"`... etc

Hope this helps.

Comment: This returns results for only the '$', whereas there are so many currency types offered by MS Excel.
For all others it returns '-1', making it virtually impossible to use it any further.

Isnt there any way in which i can get a unique number, or id, or anything irrespective of the visual formatting like font, color, etc?

Comment: Perfect, on inspecting the cell() it is showing me the currency for the format that i specify in excel.  However, how do i get that particular string or representation in a variable?  Or rather how do i get it out so that i can use it further?

For example, if formatted as Yen, i get : [$¥-411]#,##0.00;\-[$¥-411]#,##0.00

This is in :- stylesSource -> numberFormats -> table - HashMapEntry on inspecting the cell()

All i have to now do is somehow get this value outside so that i can use it further....

Any ideas?

Comment: I solved it....using the getDataFormatString() method.

Many thanks, you have no idea how much you have helped me...

Cheers :)